# What is the difference between NL and NEWLINE in tokenizer.py?

Tags: python, tokenize

I'm trying to rewrite [tokenizer.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/22f2784a276e/Lib/tokenize.py) for Java so I can parse Python in Java, but I don't understand the difference between `NL` and `NEWLINE` in the source. They seem to mean the same thing, but if they did then where are there two tokens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some googling provided this answer:

Token value used to indicate a non-terminating newline. The NEWLINE token indicates the end of a logical line of Python code; NL tokens are generated when a logical line of code is continued over multiple physical lines.

as stated from here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html

and more in depth information can be found here:

[Python 2 newline tokens in tokenize module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519046/python-2-newline-tokens-in-tokenize-module)

Comment: Oh, I've just been looking at this offline and had no internet. I should read the docs again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to marsh's answer, if you look into the code, you can see that there is a difference in [line 577](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/22f2784a276e/Lib/tokenize.py#l577) (others `NL` occurrences being `in (NEWLINE, NL)`):

```
yield TokenInfo(NL if parenlev > 0 else NEWLINE,
       token, spos, epos, line)
```

where `parenlev` keeps track of parenthesis' level:

```
if initial in '([{':
    parenlev += 1
elif initial in ')]}':
    parenlev -= 1
```

so `NEWLINE` indicates the end of the "statement", and `NL` the end of the line, but not the statement.